# Have Parent Component Wait till Child has emitted data back to parent ? (Using Vue 2)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Context -
I have a large form that I've broken up into components. I'm going to focus on only one parent/child component relationship for brevity here.

Doing some validation on each child component. Emitting back to parent when a submit button is clicked on the parent.

I have a submit button on the parent. When clicked I am emitting all child component data back to the parent

I have a method on the parent that receives the emitted data. As well as an object instantiated on the parent data() method to assign to the incoming data.

Problem -
When you hit submit, the emitted data is present on the child component, but it's empty on the parent. The submit method finishes before the emitting method finishes.

Is there a best way of accomplishing this?

I could take all inputs and put them in one giant form.. but I hate that approach.
I've tried setTimeout for a brief second. This seems to work at times, but it feels so hacky. I delay the submit method from finishing.. allowing the emit to finish.. that just doesn't feel sustainable or right.

Is there a clear way of doing this?  Thank you so much for the assistance.

```
  <1-- Parent -->
 <template>
        <!-- CHILD -->
        <LabExposureType v-if="lab" 
              @passLabExposureToParent="exposureOnSubmit">
        </LabExposureType>
      <div class="submitAndClear d-flex justify-center pb-3">
          <v-btn color="success" class="mr-4" @click="submit">submit</v-btn>
      </div>
</template>
    data(){
    exposureVals:{},      
    }
    //Removed some data and others for brevity
    methods:{
              submit() {
                  //collect vals before doing this
                  //Exposure values
                  console.log('emitted exposure vals', this.exposureVals); <- this of course is empty has the below has not finished
                 },
              //Emitted method
              exposureOnSubmit(input) {
                    this.exposureVals = input
                 }
    
          }
```

EDIT - Added code for more clarity

Parent -

```
<LabExposureType v-if="lab" :labState="exposureState" v-model="standardNum" 
    @passLabExposureToParent="exposureOnSubmit">
</LabExposureType>
```

CHILD -

```
   <v-text-field v-if="this.isStandardMethod" v-model="standardNum" label="Organization and Standard Number"
        class="text-caption primary--text" required :error-messages="standardNumErrors" 
        :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
        @blur="$v.standardNum.$touch()"></v-text-field>
```

props and emits -

```
  props: [ "labState", "modelValue"],
  emits:['update:modelValue'],
```

Answer (score 0):

Your child components should emit their values before the submit is ever clicked.  Best practice is to use the [v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model) directive so that the parent always has the latest value of the child.  Define the v-model name on the parent with whatever name you want, just make sure the prop name in the child component is named `modelValue` and that the value is emitted using event `update:modelValue`:

```html
<!-- Parent -->
<child v-model="searchText" />
```

```html
<!-- Child -->
<script>
export default {
  props: ['modelValue'],
  emits: ['update:modelValue']
}
</script>

<template>
  <input
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
  />
</template>
```

Comment: thanks for the assist. I made an error though. It's not Vue 3, it's Vue 2. Any difference in your solution above?

Comment: nope, actually the answer I gave you is for Vue 2

Comment: thanks @yoduh.. I couldn't get it working though.. cannot read properties of undefined value is my current response..

Comment: You'll need to provide more information.  The error is too vague for me without seeing the code to offer a solution.  If you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I may be able to help

Comment: apogoligies for the vague error. I essentially took your example nearly code for code. started in the parent and used a v-model on the component called standardNum. 
Setup the child with your recommendations. However, when you type in that emitting textbox an error occurs.  
        
       TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') 
       vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1897